# HTML5 / CSS3: 100% height layout for mobile with two divs as buttons and no overflow

Tags: html, css, height

I want to realize some mobile layout with two divs or buttons that fill the whole page 50% to 50% *(**EDIT:** underneath each other)*. 
Now when I do it with this code

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

section {
    height: 50%;
}

section>div {
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>text1</div>
</section>
<section>
    <div>text2</div>
</section>
```

the page is way too high.. Hardly surprising as the 10px margin and the 1px border enlarge the div... Also a wrapper div with a padding of 10px won't solve the problem.

How could I realize this layout where the page is not scrolling (not overflowing) but 100% heigh, with two buttons filling out the complete page (each at 50% or 70% - 30% or so) while the button itself has a margin or padding to get a small space to the page border and a e.g. 1px solid border?

Thank you in advance

^x3ro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make it even more simple, couldn't you just use CSS box-sizing - which would be supported in most mobile browsers...(I included vendor prefixes for the example).

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cJPba/)

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

section {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;    
}

section div {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    color: white;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

The box sizing property ensures that the height and width of an element aren't affected by borders, padding, or margins.

Comment: That seems to be the best solution, thanks.
But keep in mind, that you need to set html and body height to 100%! Otherwise the sections won't be 100% ;)
And also remember to remove body padding / margin.

^x3ro

Answer (score 1):

I would read [this article on design for mobile devices](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/viewport-metatag) if that's what you're designing for (there are more links at the bottom of the page you should follow).

And for your layout, do you mean [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/WWcfm/11/)? I would recommend using absolute positioning when making designs like this. It makes everything much easier and it doesn't need flow layout anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Not eyactly what I wanted but I now figured out how to do this. I'll post it in an answer to my question.

Comment: You didn't specify in your question which direction the buttons should be stacked. The proper action would be to notify me of the error so I could edit my answer (as I have now done) and mark it as correct.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I'm new here... Could you explain how to notify you? :)

Comment: If you comment on an answer, the author of that answer will be notified. I'm also pretty sure people are notified if you type @<username>, for instance @x3ro: Hello!

Answer (score 0):

**This is the solution i've been looking for:** http://jsfiddle.net/WWcfm/10/

Thanks to Codemonkey's code example, placing two boxes right beside each other, I figured out how to set them underneeth each other.

Thank you!

### *#EDIT:* Attention!

You'll need to use [normalize.css](http://jsfiddle.net/css/normalize.css). Otherwise it would look way different on your site!